# How to use split method in java the same as used in c#

Tags: java, c#

I have this code which is written in c# however, I want to convert this code from c# to java, when I use split method in java it required a String parameter however in my case I have String[], so it cannot be applied, please tell me how to transfer these 2 line of codes, you assistance is highly appreciated.

```
string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { "3B3D3B" };
string[] separatedHex = returnHex.Split(stringSeparators, 
                   StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: What is your use case? How do you want to split your string?

Comment: I would like to avoid any spaces

Comment: Yes. But you have array of single string separator. Is there possibility it will ever have more than one item?

Comment: yes, that's why I prefer to put in an array

Comment: So if you have multiple separators - how should you split it? First split by first item and then split by other? Or are they alternative delimiters?

Comment: yes, they are alternative delimiters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [C# documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) it looks like `Split(String[])` uses delimiter array as alternative delimiters.

As you have already noticed java does not have "split by array" method. But single string parameter in java is actually regular expression. Because of this you could join your your delimiters with alternative operator.

```
string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { "3B3D3B" };
string[] separatedHex = returnHex.split(String.join("|",stringSeparators));
```

But make sure your separator deos not contain any special regex characters - or make sure they are escaped with `\`

Comment: Java arrays don't have a `join` method. Perhaps you meant `String.join("|", stringSeparators);`? That would work, but be careful in case the separators themselves contain any special regex characters.

Comment: @Martin Hlavňa your answer totally makes sense however as DodgyCodeException said that Java arrays don't have a join method, so is it possible if you guys can recommend the best way to achieve this

Comment: @DodgyCodeException thanks I have forgot it is array :) updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

What about this code, let me know if this one works:

```
String stringSeparators = "3B3D3B";
String[] separatedHex = returnHex.split(stringSeparators);
```

Comment: this would work, however this is not matching my case as I need to declare stringSeperators as an array of strings

Comment: Then use `returnHex.split(stringSeparators[0])`. If `stringSeparators` contains more than 1 element, you should make that clear in your question.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException you answered my question and now it's finally working, thank you both so much for your help

Comment: @O.D I didn't answer your question; Nehorai and Martin did. I only commented. :-)